# on apple osx lion, make not in path

Tags: xcode, macos, path, makefile, installation

I am fairly new to apple and osx. I installed xcode from the app store, and now I have a make-executable in my filesystem:

```
192:~ herbert$ locate make | grep bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gnumake
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
/opt/X11/bin/gccmakedep
/opt/X11/bin/makedepend
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/cross/m68k-elf-binutils/files/binutils-makeinfo-check.patch
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/cross/mipsel-linux-binutils/files/300-001_ld_makefile_patch.patch
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libinchi-1/files/patch-INCHI-1-API_INCHI_API_gcc_so_makefile-makefile.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/science/indi/files/patch-libindi.pc.cmake.diff
/usr/X11/bin/gccmakedep
/usr/X11/bin/makedepend
/usr/bin/makeinfo
/usr/sbin/makedbm
192:~ herbert$
```

Unfortunately it is not in my path. As appending /Application/Xcode.app/Content/Developer/usr/bin/ to my path would be an options, it seems as something not to do. Can I somehow install it to /usr/... or /opt/local/...?

```
192:~ herbert$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
192:~ herbert$
```

Comment: You do not want to link or copy Xcode's toolchain into /opt/local, /usr, or anywhere else. If you want to use a _different_ toolchain, you can use MacPorts to get different versions of make, gcc, etc. But if you want to use the Xcode toolchain (which you probably do), use Apple's installer for that.

Comment: Also, you do not ever want to put anything in /opt/local that isn't part of MacPorts, or you will horribly confuse MacPorts.

Comment: @abarnert, thank you. I was asking because I already thought that cp and ln command would be a bad way to go. I installed XCode from the mac-store, and before macports works, it needs to have make and probably gcc, so I can't use macports to install xcode ;) Anyhow, I think I will need to double check om if I installed it properly, install it again, or check the settings in the GUI of xcode (to which you are referring in your answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install the Command Line Tools (or Unix Development Tools, in older versions) if you want to build from the command line.

In 4.3.1, the way to do this is to launch Xcode, open Preferences, click the Downloads tab, click the Components sub-tab, and click the Install button next to "Command Line Tools".

In earlier versions, the equivalent may be automatic, or it may be a choice in the initial installer, or it may be a separate installer to run.

There's also the `xcrun` tool, which lets you use the toolchain without installing the CLT, and for simple tasks you can, e.g., set `CC` to `xcrun clang`, `MAKE` to `xcrun make`, etc., or even hard-link `xcrun` to `/usr/local/bin/clang`, `/usr/local/bin/make`, etc. But setting up everything this way is a lot of work, and it still isn't sufficient to build many source-distributed projects.