# Installed ocamlfind (findlib), but never can find any extra package in Mac

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, opam

Just got a new Mac, Mountain Lion and I wish to make all ocaml related stuff set up.

I used the following commands:

```
opam switch 4.00.1

opam install findlib

opam install batteries
```

All are installed successfully without errors.

**But I can't use `batteries`, `bisect`, etc. Always say `package can't be found`.**

**Any idea?**

Should I set any `path` or something?

---

Edit:

For more information, I followed these steps:

```
1. install homebrew

    http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

2. Emacs for Mac OS X

    http://emacsformacosx.com/

3. Install tuareg-mode

    http://forge.ocamlcore.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=808

    http://marmalade-repo.org/
    Add to your .emacs: (require 'package) (in home directory)

    (add-to-list 'package-archives 
        '("marmalade" .
          "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
    (package-initialize)

    M-x eval-buffer to evaluate it, and then do M-x package-refresh-contents to load in the package listing.\

    ** m-x list-packages **

    select tuareg package

    click install

4. Install OCaml, OPam, rlwrap

    make sure XCode command line tool is installed: 
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921690/on-apple-osx-lion-make-not-in-path

    brew install ocaml

    brew install opam

    opam init

    brew install rlwrap

5. Install batteries-included (ocamlfind will be installed automatically)

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947667/cant-load-batteries-using-findlib-in-ocaml-toplevel

    opam switch 4.00.1

    opam install batteries

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751914/opam-package-not-running/14752071#14752071

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840236/ocaml-batteries-installation

    https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/ocamlinit

    Put the following in ~/.ocamlinit

    #use "topfind";;
    Toploop.use_silently
             Format.err_formatter (Filename.concat (Findlib.package_directory
             "batteries") "battop.ml");;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have your run the "magic" command to set-up your environment variables ?

```
eval `opam config env`
```

Comment: there's probably a mac way to do that, but since it is also a unix system, you can probably write that command in your session startup script (`~/.profile`)